# get value from key of Choices django model queryset like get_field_display

Tags: python, django

I'm trying display the value from choices in queryset, but it's show me the key. How to solve this?

```
    exp_dpto = _queryset_expenses.filter(paied=True, expired__month=current_month).annotate(total=Sum('price')).values('departament','total')
```

result:

```
<QuerySet [{'departament': 1, 'total': Decimal('55.00')}, {'departament': 4, 'total': Decimal('100.00')}]>
```

I don't want show the Key, eg: `departament:1`, I want to show: `departament:'Marketing'`

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Assuming `departament` is `ForeignKey` then you could do `.values('departament__name', 'total')` which will give you `{'departament__name': 'Marketing', 'total': Decimal('55.00')}` (assuming `Marketing` is stored in field named as `name`). Also you have typo in `departament` it should be `department`

Comment: No, 'departament' is a "choice", 
`departament = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_DEPARTAMENTS_CHOICES, verbose_name='Setor / Dpto.', default=1)`

Comment: Solved! If I remove **.values('total', 'departament')**, I can access all object like obj.get_departament_display and keep the annotate field (**Sum('price'))**